# Linux management of memory as exposed to the user

Tags: linux

I built a bank-affinity malloc implementation in linux.  It translates virtual addresses to physical addresses using /proc/[pid]/pagemap.  I know the bits that convey the bank number in the physical address, so I am able to give only pages that correspond to the bank I want to a process, mapping the pages into contiguous virtual address space with mremap.

The results are unexpected, however.  Running multiple processes with my malloc, each with affinity for a different bank, gives no performance improvement over running with the system's stock malloc.  There should be some improvement, in theory, due to absence of bank contention.  A similar kernel-based bank-affinity malloc did give quantifiable performance improvement.

Is there something I'm unaware of?  Some translation, buffer, or etc. that is keeping my user-level system from working, whereas the kernel-based system works?

Thanks